# Matplotlib animation in tkinter doesn't stop looping

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'v got this matplotlib animation running in tkinter, it works fine but it just never stops looping, when i press 'X' the window closes but i have to force shut it with the task manager.

This is the example code of how i tried to set it up:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg

import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

class Grapher(tk.Tk): # inherit Tk()
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)   
        tk.Tk.wm_title(self, "Quarantined-Grapher")

        self.fig = plt.figure()
        ax = plt.axes(xlim=(0,2), ylim=(0, 100))

        N = 4 # amount of lines
        self.lines = [plt.plot([], [])[0] for _ in range(N)]

        # give the figure and the root(which is self) to the "canvas"
        self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.fig, self)
        self.canvas.show()
        self.canvas.get_tk_widget().pack()

        anim = animation.FuncAnimation(self.fig, self.animate, init_func=self.init,
                                        frames=100, interval=1000, blit=True)
    def init(self):
        for line in self.lines:
            line.set_data([], [])
        return self.lines

    def animate(self, i):
        for j,line in enumerate(self.lines):
            line.set_data([0, 2], [10 * j,i]) # some trick to animate fake data.
        return self.lines

app = Grapher()
app.mainloop()
```

My guess is it might be the animation loop that never stops running, because only tkinter knows to stop?..

Note: *I made a graph work before, but i was using the tkinter after() method clearing and recreating data points, but it used up to much resources that i had to remake it. This way is so that i don't have to delete/create 10-50K data points every second.*

Answer (score 6):

---

#### Answering the wrong question:

This is behaving as intended (looping indefinitely).  If you would like to only run once use the `repeat` kwarg ([some what arcane docs](http://matplotlib.org/api/animation_api.html#matplotlib.animation.TimedAnimation)):

```
anim = animation.FuncAnimation(self.fig, self.animate, init_func=self.init,
                               frames=100, interval=1000, blit=True,
                               repeat=False)
```

Comment: I would like it to stop running when i close the window in case that was not clear. I just tried that and it din't do anything, something is still running in the background.

Comment: Yeah, I figured that out after I answered.  The timer call backs live in the `ani` object you create in `__init__` and will stop when that object gets gc'd (so I am a bit confused why this works at all as it should go out of scope as soon as you exit the `__init__` function).  The animation object also has a `_stop` method which should do what you want (assuming you can call it as part of the window teardown).